# CGI ustraveldocs can I change the country

Tags: us-visa

When I created an account on CGI, without notice I didn’t change the country to my country. So my account has been created at another country. How can I change it to my country?

Answer (score 4):

CGI Federal do not let you change the country your account it tied to by yourself.

You have two options :

1. Contact them and ask them to change it for you.  You can find the links to do this on their website at https://ustraveldocs.com/  (ustraveldocs.com is run by CGI Federal)
2. Create a new account for the correct country using a different email address.

I would recommend option 1 as it's the cleaner option, however it can take a few days for them to make the change.  If you're in a hurry, option 2 may be better.

Note that if you have paid any fees for the currently selected country, these can NOT be transferred to your new country.

Comment: Thank you. I’ll go with option one.